# Django setLang does not process "Next" parameter

Tags: django, translation

I'm trying to implement on-fly language change with the following code:

```
 {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
   <li>
      <form name="setLang{{ lang.1}}" action="/i18n/setlang/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
          <input name="next" type="hidden" value="http://google.com" />
         <input type="hidden" name="language" value="{{ lang.0 }}" />
        <a href="#" {% if LANGUAGE_CODE = lang.0 %} class="active" {%endif%} onclick="document.setLang{{ lang.1 }}.submit();return false;">{{ lang.0 }}</a>
      </form>
      </li>
{% endfor %}
```

It works great, the problem is that it doesn't return to URL specified in "next" field. I forced it to be "google.com" just to see how it works, but it keeps redirecting me back to my homepage.

Here is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'izolyatsia.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^izolyatsia/', include('izolyatsia.foo.urls')),
url(r'^$', 'showcase.views.home', name='home'),
# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
(r'^project/(?P<project_name>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$', 'izolyatsia.views.project'),
(r'^post/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$', 'izolyatsia.views.post'),

#Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
url(r'^wysiwyg_post/$', 'izolyatsia.views.wysiwyg_post', name='wysiwyg_post'),
url(r'', include('multiuploader.urls')),
(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
url(r'^(.*)/$', 'pages.views.show_page', name='show_page'),
```

)

I've got no idea why it doesn't work, maybe someone here can help me?

thanks in advance,
m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting to sites outside your domain is explicitly prevented by the code - the [`set_language`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/i18n.py#L15) view calls [`django.utils.is_safe_url()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/http.py#L231), which checks you're not trying to do exactly that.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you. I've cleared "next" value and it began to work the way I wanted. That's strange, because before that "next" field was empty but it was redirecting me to home page. Anyway, thank you for explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to the django doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference), where you can find that you should have the middlewares in this order in your `settings.py` file:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
)
```

maybe it can be what is happen to you with, I think.

Comment: Thanks, but no, all of the middleware was enabled.